# Passing routed value to View from Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is my action code, which receive a parameter (int id).

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    // Logic
    return View("List", id);
}
```

My URL is something like: `Home/List/1`

I know I can return View("List") but don't know how to ad id with it, please help me.

Comment: Didn't understand your problem. are you in home controler and need to go to index action? try Home/1

Comment: @Reno controller is same Home.

Comment: Your action is not match to url.not cleared your problem

Comment: @Imran how it is not ? I need to redirect to List and add parameter 1 after that

Comment: ok so you need to use on return  "redirecttoaction" rather then "view".you can see in arjun answer for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like [Controller.RedirectToAction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
return RedirectToAction("List", new { Id = id});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller logic you most likely would want take the id parameter to fetch some data/do some processing and then return a model to your view.

Please check the [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for some fine tutorials on MVC.

If you just want to pass the ID from the route to the view, you could either use the ViewBag or have your View accept an int model, which you then could pass like

```
return View("List", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction("List", new { id =  Id })
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using routes like this

```
    //products
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Product","s/{storeid}/{storename}/p/{productId}/{SeName}",
    new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Product", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { productId = @"\d+", storeId = @"\d+" }, 
    new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

then we can use like this.

```
return RedirectToRoute("Product",new { storeid=123, storename="name",productId=23,SeName="something"});
```